# Merge two spatial polygon data frames that have the same geometries and different attributes introduces duplicates/additional row names in R

Tags: r, spatial-join, sf, duplicates

I have two multi polygon data frames that originate from the same spatial data frame. So, the polygons should be exactly the same. I calculated some stuff and now I have used `st_join` as follows:

`final_spdf <- st_join(spfd1, spdf2, join = st_intersects, left=FALSE)`

Both `spdf1` and `spdf2` have 7038 rows before joining. After this join, the `final_spdf` has 14732 rows and when I check out the spatial data.frame, it seems like many rows are somehow duplicated? So, there are as you can see here

[image: Screenshot of the joined spatial data frame]

new row names introduced (1.1, 1.2 etc.). The rows have varying 'duplicates', sometimes none. Sometimes even the scores are different for the 'other versions' of a row.

Could it have something to do with the simple feature [attribute-geometry-relationship](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html#how-attributes-relate-to-geometries)?

Here is a screenshot of the final, joined spatial data frame:

[image: overview of the final spatial data frame]

Comment: Do the geometries have some unique identifier that can be used to join by?

Comment: that would be possible via the area size or if I created a unique ID. But then, how would I join these spatial data frames by their unique identifier? Because merge doesn't work with spatial data frames..

Comment: You make some unique identifier, then make one of data.frames not spatial using st_set_geometry(df, NULL). Then use a tidyverse join to join them together. You end up with a spatial data.frame with all columns together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a unique identifier to do a traditional join on instead of doing a spatial join.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(digest)
library(sf)

spfd1$unique_id = sapply(spfd1$geometry, digest, algo='md5')
spfd2$unique_id = sapply(spfd2$geometry, digest, algo='md5')

# switch to regular data.frame for one of them so that the geometry
# column is not duplicated.
spfd2 = st_set_geometry(spfd2, NULL)

spfd3 = spfd1 %>%
    left_join(spfd2, by='unique_id')
```